# ArcPy script extremely slow with Search and Update Cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, performance

I have developed a Python script to automatically retrieve the maximum height in a certain distance around my input polygon feature class. The height should be calculated for each 5 meters.

For a small input with around 50 polygon features, the script takes around 5 minutes. Whenever I input a really large dataset (10.000 features), the script gets extremely slow and after hours interrupts.

My (pseudo) code is as follows:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['FID']) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            my_fid = row[0]
            expression = '"FID" = ' + str(my_fid)
            fc_tmp = r"fc.shp"
            arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, fc_tmp, expression)
            
            output_tmp = r"output_tmp.shp"
            arcpy.management.CreateFeatureclass(r"", output_tmp)

            -- pseudo code
            # 1) Buffer  feature class
            # 2) Clip DGM to raster
            # 3) convert feature class to polyline
            # 4) Make points along polyline
            # 5) make tmp result feature class
            # 6) Buffer points
            # 7) get max height in buffer around points using zonal stats
            # 8) join max height with tmp result feature class
            
            with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(output_tmp, ["FID"]) as recs:
                for rec in recs:
                    rec[0] = my_fid
                    recs.updateRow(rec)
                del rec, recs

            arcpy.management.Append(output_tmp, r"myResult.shp", "NO_TEST")
            arcpy.management.Delete(output_tmp)
            arcpy.management.Delete(fc_tmp)
        del row, rows
```

Can it have to do something with the cursors?
I thought maybe the selection takes long because the feature has to be selected from 10.000 features, but the selection is done very fast.
I do not understand that when I input 10.000 features, also the first 50 features are not done within 5 minutes, although when I input onyl 50 features, it does not take longer than 5 minutes. I just tested it, the first 3 features are done within 20 minutes. Thats absolutely disproportionate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whenever I see someone using a cursor inside another cursor I suggest that they load one of the cursors values into a dictionary and then just read from it within the other cursor.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint! Could you post an example or point to one?

Comment: Any examples are likely to include ArcPy, SearchCursor, dictionary and/or list comprehension.  You'll need to know how to load values from one or more fields into a list or dictionary comprehension using a SearchCursor.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barcpy%5D+%5Bdictionary%5D+comprehension

Comment: [Turbo Charging Data Manipulation with Python Cursors and Dictionaries](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-blog/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and/ba-p/884079)

Comment: You'll see a major improvement if you load the results into a dictionary and not nest your cursors.

Comment: I just noticed that I actually do not need the updateCursor, because I append the output_tmp feature class to another feature class. Then I make the output_tmp feature class empty again and for the next feature, it will be filled again and appended. So I deleted the updateCursor and still get the desired results. I based my code on an example, so I was not aware about that. My code is still extremely slow, if I use a large polygon dataset as input..

Comment: The FID column of a shapefile is not editable (since it's an indicator of physical ordering). Your `del` inside the `with` block should corrupt the cursor after the first row. It seems as if a simple pair of Search and Insert cursors would be a better solution than creating a new feature class for each row then deleting it.

Comment: Please understand that cursor will iterate over every row you have in a layer. So basically you are updating your feature class as many times as you have rows in your fc-layer. And on top of that you are iterating over other layer rows for every row in search cursor. No wonder it is slow.. Please do not nest cursors and use array or list to store your fids. And simple if "in" array/list will do the job :)